# Arduino - Optimisation for Arduino based math calculator?

Tags: c++

How can I optimise my code?

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLM = 4;

char keys[ROWS][COLM] =
{
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {13, 12, 11, 10};
byte colmPins[COLM] = {9, 8, 7, 6};

Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colmPins, ROWS, COLM);

int arrayj[2];
int i;

long result;

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop ()
{
  char customKey = keypad.getKey();

  if (customKey != NO_KEY && i <= 1)
  {
    arrayj[i] = (translate(customKey));
    Serial.println(arrayj[i]);
    i++;
  }
}

int translate (int x) {
  int y = x - '0';
  return y;
}

int addition(int x, int y) 
{
  result = x + y
  return result;
}
```

So far it can store two values from a keypad however the idea is to add, subtract, multiply and divide; does anyone have any insight on this project.

Thanks any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Does the code *work* (a hard requirement)? Then IMO this is more suitable for [the Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so your code here can be optimized in several ways. Using methods for operators that are already built in to C++ is not very optimal. Also rather than the methods returning an integer, it would be better to return a long, double or float.

**Here is your optimized code**

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLM = 4;

char keys[ROWS][COLM] =
{
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {13, 12, 11, 10};
byte colmPins[COLM] = {9, 8, 7, 6};

Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colmPins, ROWS, COLM);

int num_array[2];
int iteration;

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop ()
{
  char customKey = keypad.getKey();

  if (customKey != NO_KEY && iteration <= 1)
  {
    num_array[iteration] = (translate(customKey));
    Serial.println(num_array[iteration]);
    iteration ++;
  }
}

int translate (int x) 
{
  return x - '0';
}
```

**Changes:**

I returned the values rather than make an entirely new variable to store the result of the methods. I also changed some variable names to make them more maintainable.